# Convert an element of a ruby array to a string

Tags: ruby

I am getting an array with a single element in it, `["http://i.foobar.com/This-Is-The-Remainder-Of-The-Link.jpg"]` and I'm trying to render it as just the URL to display an image. Any thoughts on the best way to do this? Currently when I render it in HTML I get `[&quot;http://i.foobar.com/This-Is-The-Remainder-Of-The-Link.jpg&quot;]`

Comment: Umm, what's wrong with `a[0]` or `a.first`?

Comment: You need to provide more information. the "&quote;" is HTML escaping of the quote character. What is doing this escaping? (ERB in Rails?) You need to know this, because the proper way to solve this is something like "<img src='#{a.first}' />" but if the quote is escaped, then the HTML characters will be, too, so this will display in your page as text rather than being interpreted as code. (If you're in Rails, its best to use their url helpers like [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag))

Comment: ERB in Rails is doing the escaping on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just be able to pull the first element. You can do this by doing the following.

```
a = ['http://someurl.com/somepath']
a.first
```

or

```
a = ['http://someurl.com/somepath']
a[0]
```